# Android List Preference with 2 line of texts for each entry

Tags: android

Can I create an Android ListPreference with 2 line of text in each selection?
1 is the title, 1 is the summary? If yes, how?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you will need to subclass ListPreference and override the [onCreateDialogView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/DialogPreference.html#onCreateDialogView%28%29) method and provide the custom chooser view you need.